# What is this metric called? log(var)/log(mean)

Tags: distributions, metric

I have come across this is a piece of code but I am struggling to find something similar with a statistical explanation.  It seems to be used in this way?

$$p = \log(\text{var})/\log(\text{mean}).$$

If $p < 1.4$ then Poisson
else if $p < 2.4$ then Gamma
else Inverse Gaussian.

Has anyone come across this type of metric and perhaps this context of selecting a distribution?

Comment: It is strange that a choice is being made between a *discrete* distribution (Poisson) and *continuous* distributions, suggesting it is *ad hoc* and might not be justified in any literature. The criterion itself can be recast as a comparison of $p\log(\bar x)$ to $\log(\sigma^2),$ which upon exponentiation compares $\sigma$ to $(\bar x)^{p/2},$ suggesting it's a kind of [spread-vs-level analysis.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22spread+versus+level%22+plot)